# Add items in reply to KnexJs

Tags: javascript, promise, knex.js

I have two tables: Sales (tbl_venda in portuguese) and Items(tbl_venda_itens in portuguese).

With the code below I can send data from the sales table

```
const db = require('./db')
const getSales = (req, res) => {
    db('tbl_venda')
        .select('tbl_venda.id_venda', 'tbl_venda.pedido', 'tbl_venda.data_venda',
            'tbl_venda.data_entrega', 'tbl_cliente.nome AS cliente', 'tbl_vendedor.nome AS vendedor',
            'tbl_venda.obs', 'tbl_venda.total_pagar', 'tbl_venda.total_bruto', 'tbl_venda.id_loja',
            'tbl_venda.horadavenda')
        .join('tbl_cliente', 'tbl_cliente.id_cliente', 'tbl_venda.id_cliente')
        .join('tbl_vendedor', 'tbl_vendedor.id_vendedor', 'tbl_venda.id_vendedor')
        .where('data_venda', '>=', req.body.dateInitial)
        .where('data_venda', '<=', req.body.dateFinal)
        .orderBy('id_venda')
        .then(rows => res.status(201).send(rows))
        .catch(error => showError(error, res))
}
```

db.js

```
const options = {
    client: 'mysql2',
    connection: {
        ...
    }
}

const knex = require('knex')(options)
module.exports = knex
```

But I need to add the items from each sale. I tried to do something like this:

```
const getSales = (req, res) => {
    db('tbl_venda')
        .select('tbl_venda.id_venda', 'tbl_venda.pedido', 'tbl_venda.data_venda',
            'tbl_venda.data_entrega', 'tbl_cliente.nome AS cliente', 'tbl_vendedor.nome AS vendedor',
            'tbl_venda.obs', 'tbl_venda.total_pagar', 'tbl_venda.total_bruto', 'tbl_venda.id_loja',
            'tbl_venda.horadavenda')
        .join('tbl_cliente', 'tbl_cliente.id_cliente', 'tbl_venda.id_cliente')
        .join('tbl_vendedor', 'tbl_vendedor.id_vendedor', 'tbl_venda.id_vendedor')
        .where('data_venda', '>=', req.body.dateInitial)
        .where('data_venda', '<=', req.body.dateFinal)
        .orderBy('id_venda')
        .then(rows => {
            return rows.map(row => {
                return db('tbl_venda_itens')
                    .select('tbl_venda_itens.id_venda_itens', 'tbl_venda_itens.id_venda',
                        'tbl_fornecedor.nome_fantasia AS fabricante', 'tbl_venda_itens.quantidade',
                        'tbl_estoque.descricao AS produto', 'tbl_venda_itens.valor_unitario',
                        'tbl_venda_itens.valor_total', 'tbl_venda_itens.cor', 'tbl_venda_itens.desconto',
                        'tbl_venda_itens.preco_final')
                    .join('tbl_fornecedor', 'tbl_venda_itens.id_fornecedor', 'tbl_fornecedor.id_fornecedor')
                    .join('tbl_estoque', 'tbl_venda_itens.id_estoque', 'tbl_estoque.id_estoque')
                    .where('id_venda', '=', row.id_venda)
                    .then(values => {
                        const newRow = { ...row, item: { ...values } }
                        return newRow
                    })
            })
        })
        .then(values => res.status(201).send(values))
        .catch(error => showError(error, res))
```

}

It doesn't work, I only receive empty objects.

Comment: You need to use `Promise` all

Comment: How would I use it in this context?

Comment: On the array of promises that the `map()` call returns

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand where and how to write this in my code. I'm a beginner, I'll try to read more to find out where to use Promise.all

Comment: Can you exemplify how it would look?

Comment: Add a `console.log(values)` to the handler to understand what's happening. The empty objects are only a JSON representation.

Comment: I didn't know you could do that with Promise. I only knew the following example: Promise.all([
  new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1500)),
  new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 900)),
  new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 2200))
])
.then(results => results.length.b.c)
.then(c => console.info(c))
.catch(err => console.error(err))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const getSales = (req, res) => {
    db('tbl_venda')
        .select('tbl_venda.id_venda', 'tbl_venda.pedido', 'tbl_venda.data_venda',
            'tbl_venda.data_entrega', 'tbl_cliente.nome AS cliente', 'tbl_vendedor.nome AS vendedor',
            'tbl_venda.obs', 'tbl_venda.total_pagar', 'tbl_venda.total_bruto', 'tbl_venda.id_loja',
            'tbl_venda.horadavenda')
        .join('tbl_cliente', 'tbl_cliente.id_cliente', 'tbl_venda.id_cliente')
        .join('tbl_vendedor', 'tbl_vendedor.id_vendedor', 'tbl_venda.id_vendedor')
        .where('data_venda', '>=', req.body.dateInitial)
        .where('data_venda', '<=', req.body.dateFinal)
        .orderBy('id_venda')
        .then(rows => {
            const requests = rows.map(row => {
                return db('tbl_venda_itens')
                    .select('tbl_venda_itens.id_venda_itens', 'tbl_venda_itens.id_venda',
                        'tbl_fornecedor.nome_fantasia AS fabricante', 'tbl_venda_itens.quantidade',
                        'tbl_estoque.descricao AS produto', 'tbl_venda_itens.valor_unitario',
                        'tbl_venda_itens.valor_total', 'tbl_venda_itens.cor', 'tbl_venda_itens.desconto',
                        'tbl_venda_itens.preco_final')
                    .join('tbl_fornecedor', 'tbl_venda_itens.id_fornecedor', 'tbl_fornecedor.id_fornecedor')
                    .join('tbl_estoque', 'tbl_venda_itens.id_estoque', 'tbl_estoque.id_estoque')
                    .where('id_venda', '=', row.id_venda)
                    .then(values => {
                        const newRow = { ...row, itens: [...values] }
                        return newRow
                    })
                    .catch(error => showError(error, res))
            })
            return Promise.all(requests)
        })
        .then(values => res.status(201).send(values))
        .catch(error => showError(error, res))
}
```

Font: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/promise-all-in-javascript-with-example-6c8c5aea3e32/